# How to use `GET` parameters in a HTML document?

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery-mobile, get

I have a HTML document and I want to send a parameter.

Let's name the document `Categoty`, and all it do it sends a request to the server (via Ajax) to get something on this categoty.

Suppose I'm using PHP, I would simply send the parameter:

`localhost/Categoty.php?cat=somecat`,

and read it in the PHP document: `$_GET['cat']`.

My question is if there's something similar in HTML (or Javascript)?

I though about hashtag (.i.e. `categoty.html#somecat`) , but I'm using jQuery mobile in my Android Hybrid application so it makes some issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe JS's `window.location.search` is what you're looking for?

Comment: @Teemu Yes! `window.location.search.substring(5)` did the work. thank you sooo much ;)

Answer (score 0):

use the `jQuery URL Parser` in this [link](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser) and then try:

```
jQuery.url().param('cat');
```

you can also access all other info we usually need in terms of dealing with GET parameters, like:

```
jQuery.url().attr('protocol');
```

returns the URL protocol like: `http` or `https`

```
jQuery.url().attr('host')
```

returns the host like `stackoverflow.com`

you can also get the segments of your URL like this:

```
jQuery.url().segment(1);//for instance in this very page's url it returns "posts"
```

at the end:

`jQuery.url().param('cat')` in javascript does the same as `$_GET['cat']` does in PHP

Comment: This answer was tagged as low quality. Add a bit of explanation or risk deletion.

Comment: Why to provide methods to get protocol or host as an answer, as OP obviously wants to get the search string?

Comment: these all are related to How to use `GET` parameters in js, whether it is a querystring or the other attributes in the url. it is a jQuery plugin with all these which allows you to get parameters without you needing go thru string parsing , but if you want to do this with raw javascript your solution (`window.location.search`) is the one.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery ajax can do it , use $.ajax();

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost/Categoty.php?cat=somecat',
    success: function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use jQuery